# Cookies on external server

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using the code below to handle cookies, it works fine locally, but when I upload it to our testserver the cookies are not set (it's the same for Firefox, IE and Chrome, so I don't think it's a browser issue).

Cookies are allowed since I can set cookies using PHP `setcookie("RFT_reeftWpLang", $lang, time()+29030400, dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]), $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);`

Neither locally nor on the server I get any errors when I try to set document.cookie, but on the server `console.log( getFilterCookie(cname));` return an empty string where I do get the expected value locally.

I know you probably can not say what's wrong without access to the server, but I hope you might tell me what to look for in order to pinpoint the error

```
function setFilterCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var cookiePath = "/";
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    if (pathArray.length > 2 && $.trim(pathArray[1]) != "" ) {
        cookiePath = cookiePath+pathArray[1];
    }
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
    try {
        document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires+"; domain="+window.location.host+"; path="+cookiePath ;
    } catch (e) {console.log(e);}
    if(exdays < 0) {
        document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
    }
    console.log( getFilterCookie(cname));
}

function getFilterCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = $.trim(ca[i]);
        if (c.indexOf(name)==0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function delFilterCookie(cname) {
    setFilterCookie(cname, "", -1);
}
```

Comment: check whether expires , path , domain properties of cookies are set correctly and are valid. Also whether the cookies are https only or not

Comment: How do I see if cookies are https only?

Comment: Open Developer Tools in your browser, go to storage (or something similar). There cookies should be listed and most browsers also show whether it is HttpOnly or not. 

But it should not be possible for Javascript to set these cookies in the first place. So I doubt whether this is the problem.

Comment: you can see it in the place where they are set (eg in the server). if the `httpsOnly` (php, similar for other platforms)  property is set then they are https only

Answer (score 0):

Thank for helping

On our testserver we have the port in the url, so it get's part of the domain, it works's after I have changed my code to

```
var domainArray = window.location.host.split( ':' );
var domain = domainArray[0];

try {
console.log(document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires+"; domain="+domain+"; path="+cookiePath);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log("fail setFilterCookie"  + cname + " - " + cvalue + " - " + exdays);}
```